# 2D Neumann Conditions on Irregular Domain

Tags: finite-difference

I would like to model the 2D diffusion equation with Neumann BC's inside the following egg-shaped domain:

[image: IMG]

I would like to use the finite difference method with the discretization implied by the image above, but while I can handle the interior points, I don't know how to handle the boundary values. I know how to search for and identify the boundary points, but I'm not sure what finite-difference approximation to the no-flux condition I should use. Currently I'm thinking of estimating the direction of the normal at each boundary point by looking at it's 8 nearest neighbors, and then, if the normal is approximately

$$\textbf{n} = [n_1, n_2]$$

I would add an equation like:

$$\mathbf{\nabla} c \cdot \textbf{n} \approx \frac{c_{i,j}-c_{i-1,j}}{\Delta x} \times n_1 + \frac{c_{i,j}-c_{i,j-1}}{\Delta y} \times n_2 = 0$$

Though of course I'll need to be careful which side I take the derivative from.

Does anyone have any suggestions or resources for this type of problem? Examples in 3D would be particuarly useful, as that's where I'm working towards.

Comment: What is the domain? The red egg?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'll change that.

Comment: There are plenty of methods to deal with boundary conditions on oddly shaped domains using finite difference methods. What literature have you already looked for?

Comment: I can't say I've found a lot :) My experience with FDM's doesn't extend much beyond Numerical Recipes. The problem I actually want to solve involves modelling anisotropic diffusion inside a 3D brain, and the boundary there is already discretized for me and is terribly irregular. Most of what I've found so far relates to solving PDE's on a domain with a known function (e.g. on a ellipse) and you make clever discretizations. But I can't do that: my discretization is given. I would very much appreciate recommendations of textbooks/papers dealing with this issue :)

Comment: Try https://www.google.com/search?q=finite+difference+non+uniform+grid+irregular+domain+boundary+condition&oq=finite+difference+non+uniform+grid+irregular+domain+boundary+condition&aqs=chrome..69i57.27966j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8 
It shows 179,000 hits.

Comment: If you are using this Poisson like method and benefiting from SOR type of solutions, then you could simply encode them in your matrix. Did you already try this?

Comment: So far I've managed to get some results by using the standard, discretized Laplacian at the interior points, and using 'ghost points' at the boundaries. Because I want the homogeneous Neumann condition, the ghost points basically give (in 1D): $u_1 - u_{-1} = 0$ (in other words $u_1 = u_{-1}$), and so in my code I just go through and replace the ghost points ($u_{-1}$) with the corresponding internal point ($u_1$) on the other side of the boundary point.

Comment: This all works fine, but handling corners becomes more difficult when I add Anisotropic diffusion, as I need to worry about diagonal points (like $u_{i+1,j+1}$ relative to $u_{ij}$). So far I've just said that, at the corner points on the boundary, there should be no flux in the diagonal direction, and so $u_{1,1}=u_{-1,-1}$ and I use this to eliminate the ghost point $u_{-1,-1}$. This is running into a little trouble when the anisotropic diffusion matrix is only just positive-definite, but overall it looks to be doing alright.

Comment: My main concern here is really that I'm handling a lot of this in a very amateurish way, which could lead to instabilities/errors down the track. A textbook or a reference to someone solving a problem like this would be handy :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you'll get the boundary conditions you want automatically if you construct your discrete Laplacian in terms of an adjacency matrix, minus the sum of the number of neighbors along the diagonal.

Consider the 1D case:

- In the interior, the discrete Laplacian is $\{1,-2,1\}$. That is, the adjacent cells $\{1,0,1\}$ minus their sum ($-2$) along the diagonal.
- At i.g. a right boundary, the cell to the right is missing so you get $\{1,-1,0\}$ for the local operation

The analogous construction in 2D is similar. Following the guidance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator#Implementation_via_operator_discretization), you can include the four corners in your Laplacian in a way that maximizes rotational symmetry within the constraints of a square grid, which will help with the "corners"

Here's some scipy code exploring this. Note how pixels outside the boundary are masked out of the adjacency matrix before calculating the value of the diagonal for the discrete Laplacian operator.

```
from pylab import *
import scipy

# Define square grid and region mask
L       = 64
grid    = linspace(-1,1,L)[:,None] + 1j*linspace(-1.5,1.5,L)[None,:]
mask    = abs(grid)**2<.9
nanmask = float32([NaN,1])[int32(mask)]
imshow(mask,cmap='gray');
title('Region to simulate'); axis('off'); 
savefig('1.png')
show()

# Build a discrete Laplacian operator
A1d = eye(L,k=-1) + eye(L,k=1) + eye(L,k=L-1) + eye(L,k=1-L) 
A2d_cross  = scipy.sparse.kronsum(A1d,A1d).toarray()
A2d_corner = scipy.sparse.kron(A1d,A1d).toarray()
Ad = A2d_cross*2/3+A2d_corner*1/3
Ad[~mask.ravel(),:] = Ad[:,~mask.ravel()] = 0
Lp = Ad - diag(sum(Ad,0))

# Simplify adjacency matrix for speed
M = float32(Lp)
keep = any(M>0,0) | any(M>0,1)
M = M[keep][:,keep]
NPOINTS = sum(keep)

# Get eigenmodes
NMODES = 49
η,V  = scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh(scipy.sparse.bsr_matrix(M),
                                 k=NMODES,which='LA')
# Plot eigenmodes
figure(figsize=(5,5))
subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1,0,0)
k = int(ceil(sqrt(NMODES)))
for i in range(NMODES):
    subplot(k,k,i+1)
    the_mode = zeros((L,L))
    the_mode[keep.reshape(L,L)] = V[:,i]
    scale = np.max(abs(the_mode))
    imshow(the_mode*nanmask,vmin=-scale,vmax=scale,cmap='coolwarm')
    axis('off')
suptitle('Eigenmodes—Neumann boundary zero')
savefig('2.png')
show()
```

And its figure outputs:

[image]

[image]